# How to configure CORS on Swisscom Cloudfoundry S3 dynamic storage

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, swisscomdev

I need to setup some CORS rules for my S3 Bucket hosted on Swisscom Cloudfoundry. Where or how can i set my CORS rules?

In the Cloudfoundry dashboard I can't find any settings, that belongs to CORS.

And setting CORS through the [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTcors.html)  with the Postman App (using the AWS Signature Authentication method) gives me the following Exception:

```
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Secret Access Key and signing method. For more information, see REST Authentication and SOAP Authentication for details.</Message>
    <RequestId>8abebc99:1683be0bcde:5db02:2c2f</RequestId>
</Error>
```

Does Swisscom Cloudfoundry S3 support CORS settings?
How can i set CORS rules?

Answer (score 0):

Swisscoms Dynamic Storage is based on Dell EMCs Elastic Cloud Storage. You can define your CORS setting according to the official documentation provided by Dell EMC: http://doc.isilon.com/ECS/3.3/API/S3BucketCorsOperations_setBucketCors_7609e2df22a3c1aba6f55696c1eb3fc3_ba672412ac371bb6cf4e69291344510e_detail.html

The error message you posted suggests that there is an issue with the signature calculation. This can be caused by you system clock getting out of sync.